# Calling a Method in Response to a Stream Event

Tags: ios, objective-c, stream

When my app connects to a server I want it to automatically send a message to the server. Right now the app connects on its own, and when a button is pressed the following method is called:

```
- (void)getChallenge {
    // Open connection and send challenge command
    NSString *h = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H\n"];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[h2dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [self.outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
    NSLog(@"%@", h);
}
```

That method works properly when an IBAction method calls it. But when I call this method in response to a stream event, it hands on the write line and the NSLog entry is never made. I have been using:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

    switch (streamEvent) {

        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            [self stopConnectionTimer];
            [self getChallenge];
            break;
```

How can I get this method to execute in response to the stream connecting instead of relying on a user command?

Comment: Does it even call the method getChallenge? What does stopConnectionTimer do?

Comment: I have an NSTimer to kill a connection if it takes too long. It is called and completes. GetChallenge is called but never completes. When I step through it just hangs on the write command, and a packet sniffer shows the data is never sent.

Comment: Im sorry but its hard for me to identify the issue. All I can think of, is that there might be a problem with the specific thread you are using.
I would suggest looking at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/WritingOutputStreams.html
Sorry I couldn't be of more help.